# Face rekognition in streaming video returns just one frame for each second

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I'm trying to run face recognition on live stream via amazon rekogntion and kinesis services. I've configured kinesis video stream for input video, stream processor for recognition and kinesis data stream to get results from the stream processor. All is working good, but I'm getting just one frame for each second in the stream.

I calculate frame timestamp accordignly:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/streaming-video-kinesis-output.html
by adding the `ProducerTimestamp` and `FrameOffsetInSeconds` field values together and get timestamps with defference 1 second.

For instance:

```
1528993313.0310001
1528993314.0310001
1528993314.0310001
```

I use demo app for video streaming from Java Producer SDK
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-java.git

Total duration of data from stream processor is correct and equals the video file duration, but as I said I get just on frame for each second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question following some further research. As of today, Rekognition Streaming Video has restriction and analyses just one frame per second.